# matplotlib scale axes according to arbitrary function

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am plotting a 5th degree polynomial... for simplicity, lets just go with `y=(x-3)(x-2)x(x+2)(x+3)`.  On reasonable intervals for `x`, say from -5 to 5, the graph isn't very informative because the function grows very quickly outside of the "interesting" range, about -3 to 3:

[image]

A [symlog scale](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.yscale.html) is somewhat better, but now I'm looking at the log of a 5th degree polynomial, which is a bit hard for me to interpret:

[image]

Ideally, I could plot this on a polynomial scale.  Since I know I have a 5th degree polynomial, then a 5th root scale would be able to fit all of my data, and the graph should behave linearly out near the edges.  Is it possible to scale my axes with an arbitrary function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I adjusted this [example](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/scales/scales.html) as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

y = np.random.normal(loc=0.5, scale=0.4, size=1000)
x = np.arange(len(y))

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6, 8), constrained_layout=True)

t = np.arange(1, 170.0, 0.1)
s = t / 2.

ax.plot(t, s, '-', lw=2)
ax.set_yscale('function', functions=(lambda x: x**5, lambda x: x**(0.2)))
ax.grid(True)
ax.set_ylim(0,5)
plt.show()
```

Comment: I'm surprised that really worked.  You don't want xaxis and yaxis, your want forward and inverse `functions=(lambda x: x**5, lambda x: x**(0.2))`